# Loading hyperref package causes my document to fail compiling

Tags: bibliographies, hyperref, overleaf, hyperlink

I use overleaf to write my LaTeX documents. Apologies if this is messy, I am quite new to this. My bibliography formats nearly how I want it:

[image]

But I have seen in documents made by other people that their URLs are blue and are clickable, so when they press the URL on the reference, it takes them to the actual page the URL leads to. Additionally, this blue hyperlink feature also occurs elsewhere in their document, acting as a hyperlink between parts inside the document, for example:

[image]

the picture above is from another document, and the 9 in figure 9 is blue, and if I click it, it takes me to figure 9. I want that in my document. I found out I simply need to load a package, hyperref, to achieve this. However, when I try to load it in, it immediately stops the overleaf compiling and is unable to produce anything. Here is my pre-amble:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, allcolors=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\graphicspath{ {./images/} }
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[left=2cm, right=2cm]{geometry} %this is the margin size.
 \setlength {\marginparwidth }{2cm} %confirming the margin width for todonotes?
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
```

so if I run that, the document instantly fails to compile, but if i remove the line used to generate the blue hyperlinks:

```
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, allcolors=blue]{hyperref}
```

The document compiles as normal. How can I fix this?

Comment: `hyperref` must be loaded after all other packages.

Comment: Remove the inputenc line. It is unneeded and utf8x can do harm.

Comment: "fails to compile" does not tell us the reported error;  your preamble used in a new document generates no error.

Comment: Off-topic: Do you really use both: `subfig` *and* `subcaption`? I would suggestion to user *either* `subfig` *or* `subcaption`. And because both of them require and implicitly load `caption` you don't need to load `caption` explicitly.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer thank you, this solved it for me.